# Is there a good reason why I can use a polite form before から but not before ので?

Tags: politeness, classical-japanese, particle-から, subordinate-clauses, old-japanese

Does anybody know why - historically, etymologically or logically - one can use polite forms (e.g. -ます) in causal subordinate clauses before から, while one must use the plain form before ので?

Comment: Why do you think that you can't use that combination...? (in short, yes you can)

Comment: ^ [こういうの](https://www.facebook.com/notes/lets-learn-japanese-together/ーので-using-node-to-mean-becauseasdue-to/10150158328995648/) があるからかな・・・ [ここにも](https://www.facebook.com/notes/lets-learn-japanese/凄く大きい鳥だったのでびっくりしましたbecause-it-was-an-amazingly-large-bird-we-were-surprised-usin/119702431387817/)。。 「この会議は大切なので、良子さんは丁寧な人ので、良子さんを持って行ってください。」だって～・・ふえええ

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the linked post, and Chocolate and Bjorn's comment - you totally can use ので and から after the ~ます　form of a verb.

When I lived in Japan I heard people say,　`行きますから` and  `行きますので`

If you want to know the difference, you can check out [This website ~ Kara vs Node](http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2015/10/29/a-tale-of-two-japanese-because-words-node-%EF%BC%88%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%EF%BC%89vs-kara-%EF%BC%88%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%EF%BC%89/%22%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89vs%20%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%22), it does a great job of explaining. But a basic difference is that から is less formal than ので.

Comment: That is so weird: my textbook says that ので should always be preceded by the plain form…. Whereas it gives both options for から.

Anyways, thanks for clearing that up!